# What are the official resources available for guild recruitment?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

What are the official (provided by Blizzard) resources (forums, websites, in-game mechanics) for guild recruitment or for finding a guild that fits your criteria?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75557/discussion-on-question-by-mart10-what-are-the-official-resources-available-for-g). If you wish to discuss this question's on/off topicness, please do so on [this meta discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12962/28182)